# Intrinsic Fused-Multiply-Add : Can I use same variables for input and output?

Tags: simd, intrinsics

Can I use the same variable (here `_res_`) as input **and** output for `_mm256_fmadd_ps` to act as an accumulator or will it cause undefined behaviour because I am reading and writing to the same registry at the same time?

```c
__m256 A1, B1;
__m256 A2, B2;
__m256 A3, B3;
/* Init all As and Bs */

__m256 _res = {};
_res = _mm256_fmadd_ps(A1, B1, _res); // _res += A1 * B1
_res = _mm256_fmadd_ps(A2, B2, _res); // _res += A2 * B2
_res = _mm256_fmadd_ps(A3, B3, _res); // _res += A3 * B3
```

Comment: Re "Can I use same variables for input and output?" Yes, you can.

Comment: On all CPUs I know, it is perfectly valid to use the same register for both input and output in an instruction.  Certainly on x86.  And even if it weren't, it's legal in C to assign to a variable a function of itself, so your compiler would use different registers if it were necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, that's perfectly normal; intrinsics functions work like pure functions that take numeric args by value, just as they're defined and documented.**

If there were any asm quirks to worry about, the compiler would take care of them; that's the benefit of using intrinsics in C instead of hand-written asm.

In this case there aren't any problems; with `vfmadd231ps ymm0, ymm1, ymm2`, it can make the addend the destination of the FMA.  As opposed to [`vfmadd132ps` or `vfmadd213ps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vfmadd132ps:vfmadd213ps:vfmadd231ps), where one of the multiplicands is the input/output register.

I would recommend `__m256 _res = _mm256_setzero_ps();` instead of an empty brace initializer.  Or of course `__m256 res = _mm256_mul_ps(A1, B1)` so the compiler doesn't have to materialize a `0.0f` vector and FMA into it.

Also, don't use leading underscores in your own local var names.  It's not good style, and it's very close to [names that are reserved for the implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).  `_res` *is* reserved at global scope, and `_Res` would be reserved everywhere, might be a macro.

---

**Where the compiler does need to do extra work is if you *weren't* updating one of the inputs to become the result**, and you used the original value of all 3 inputs later.  Then the compiler would need an extra register copy instruction (`vmovaps`) to keep the original value around after `vfmadd` replaces one of its input registers with the result.

(The 3 forms give the compiler a choice of whether to replace addend or a multiplicand. And if a multiplicand, whether the last operand which can be memory or register is the addend or another multiplicand.  `vfmadd213ps op1, op2, op3` does `fma(op2, op1, op3)`, hence the numbering scheme.)

Another case where the compiler would need an extra register-copy would be compiling `v = _mm_andnot_ps(mask, v)` without AVX, so it can only use 2-operand instructions like `andnps xmm0, xmm1`, which replace xmm0 with the result.  It's not commutative, so if we want to not destroy `mask`, we need to copy it first.  And/or if we need `v` in the same register as before (e.g. because we're in a tight loop that we're not unrolling), then we'd need also need a `movaps` for that.

---

**The only reason to think about asm details like this is to minimize register-copy instructions**, e.g. for cases like this, or in your choice of shuffles, as in my answer *[Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum (or other reduction)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-sse-vector-sum-or-other-reduction)*.

For example, SSE2 `pshufd` is a copy-and-shuffle, but `punpckhqdq` is a 2-input shuffle so it replaces its first operand.  If you want to broadcast the top qword of an integer vector and add, `hi = _mm_shuffle_epi32(v, _MM_SHUFFLE(3,2,3,2))` can avoid a `movdqa` vs. `hi = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(v,v)` if you're compiling without AVX.

Note that what really matters is the pattern of data dependencies, not whether you invent a new temporary and then assign it.  That makes no difference to an optimizing compiler.  `res = fma(a,b,res)` is handled internally by the compiler like `res2 = fma(a,b,res1)` when it converts the program logic into [SSA form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single-assignment_form), which all the major optimizing ahead-of-time compilers use internally.  e.g. LLVM-IR (clang) or GIMPLE (GCC).